# Getting error with razorpay_flutter_package

Tags: flutter, error-handling, flutter-dependencies

#Flutter_Error

The plugin `razorpay_flutter` doesn't have a main class defined in

C:\Users\LD-177\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\razorpay_flutter-1.3.5\android\src\main\java\com\razorpay\razorpay_flutter\RazorpayFlutterPlugin.java or

C:\Users\LD-177\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\razorpay_flutter-1.3.5\android\src\main\kotlin\com\razorpay\razorpay_flutter\RazorpayFlutterPlugin.kt. This islikely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage: com.razorpay.razorpay_flutter` or `mainClass` entry in the plugin's pubspec.yaml.

If you are the author of this plugin, fix the `androidPackage` entry or move the main class to any of locations used above. Otherwise, please contact the author of

this plugin and consider using a different plugin in the meanwhile.

Running the flutter new project first time but getting this error. Can anyone show step by step solution to this so I can start my flutter Journey.